# Como pasar un solo dato de una vista a otra mvc

Tags: asp.net, mvc, entity-framework

recien estoy empezando en programación y estoy haciendo una plataforma en .net de agendamiento, no se si podrían ayudarme, cuando guardo los datos de un cliente nuevo necesito que me lleve a otra pantalla y en esa pantalla me muestre solo un dato, la patente,  no tengo idea de como hacer eso, este es el código que uso donde guardo los datos y me lleva a la otra vista , espero puedan ayudarme, mil gracias!

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("IngresarClientes","Home",FormMethod.Post))
{ 

    <div class="col-md-12">
        <div>
            @Html.LabelFor(d => d.nombre)
            @Html.TextBoxFor(d => d.nombre, "", new { @class = "form-control" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(d => d.nombre, null, new { @class = "red" })
        </div>
        <div>
            @Html.LabelFor(d => d.apellido)
            @Html.TextBoxFor(d => d.apellido, "", new { @class = "form-control" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(d => d.apellido, null, new { @class = "red" })
            <div>
                @Html.LabelFor(d => d.telefono)
                @Html.TextBoxFor(d => d.telefono, "", new { @class = "form-control" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(d => d.telefono, null, new { @class = "red" })
            </div>
            <div>
                @Html.LabelFor(d => d.patente)
                @Html.TextBoxFor(d => d.patente, "", new { @class = "form-control" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(d => d.patente, null, new { @class = "red" })
            </div>
            <div>
                @Html.LabelFor(d => d.modelo)
                @Html.TextBoxFor(d => d.modelo, "", new { @class = "form-control" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(d => d.modelo, null, new { @class = "red" })
            </div>
            <br />
            <div style="text-align:right;">
                <input value="Guardar" class="btn btn-danger" type="submit" />

            </div>
        </div>
}
```

Comment: Puedes hacerlo de varias formas por ejemplo a nivel servidor en a accion de guardar si todo se guardo correctamente  puedes redirigir a otra accion mediante, RedirectToAction. Otra manera es del lado del cliente  haces un envio de datos mediante ajax al servidor para guardar si todo es correcto en la respuesta, haces un llamado a la siguiente vista. Viendo como esta implementado hasta ahora tu envio de informacion mediante el boton es mejor usar RedirectToAction averigua un poco de esto y cualquier duda la agregas a esta pregunta.